# Buddypress activity id

Tags: posts, buddypress, id

I am working on buddypress activity loop. I want to get current activity id or all activity parameters in entry.php file. but i am not able to get activity id.

I am trying to use

> bp_activity_id();

But not able to get id.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function is called right in `entry.php` as follows:

```
<li class="<?php bp_activity_css_class(); ?>" id="activity-<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>">
```

Note that `bp_activity_id()` will echo the value. To use the value in code, call `bp_get_activity_id()`.